# iOS Bring Subview To Front not working on UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview, subview

I know that I should be able to do this:

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:myImageView];
```

And that it should bring the image view to the front.   myImageView has been set in a storyboard, and linked in to the code using @property and @synthesize.   I'm able to do other manipulations (loading images and scaling up via animation) but can't seem to get the view to take up the uppermost view.  So when the animation is finished there is an overlap to another image view.

The view it's part of is a modally presented view controller.   Either on iPhone or iPad form sheet.   Not working on both.   Also running iAd.

What I find strange too is when I do:

```
NSLog(@"number of subviews %d", self.view.subviews.count);
```

I get a result of 1.

Any suggestions?   I've used this method before with other apps and it worked, but my searches suggest that I'm doing it right.   So where else have I gone wrong?   I'm thinking it must be to do with not being in the right self.view but can't understand why that would be.

Further code as requested:

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:myImageView];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.35 delay:0 options:0 animations:^{
            //save previous frame
            prevFrame = myImageView.frame;
            float width = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
            float height = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;
            // Need to create a 320x320 centred square
            float originX = (width - 320)/2;
            float originY = (height -320)/2;
            CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake( originX, originY, 320, 320);
            [myImageView setFrame:newFrame];
        }completion:^(BOOL finished){
        }];
```

So you see most of the code is just about the animation of the image to expand it to the centre of the display.   But I am able to manipulate the image as you would expect, but it's not responding to the message to take it to the front of the view.   Normally that's self.view bringSubviewToFront and that would work, but I think the message is going to the wrong view and I can't think why?

Comment: share code. Makes no sense.

Comment: It does make sense. If imageView is on top, then it it cannot bring it on top. Make sure you have correctly set up view hierarchy, give us some examples.

Comment: I've got two image views, similar code in each.   One is by default higher than the other and when it expands out (as I want) it covers the other.   That's fine.   But when I go to that other and expand it out via animation it goes under the first.   So it's not being brought to the front.   I don't understand why my call to bring it to the front is effectively being ignored.

Answer (score 0):

if you have 2 images on each other just use

```
 [imageView setHidden:YES];
```

to Hide it
and

```
[imageView setHidden:No];
```

to show it

Comment: It's a nice idea for a workaround (which does work).   I'd suggest changing the alpha within the animation as a smoother way to do it.